# How to fix Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," in index.tsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i'm occuring that problem:

> Line 9:38:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
> prettier/prettier

in index.tsx file.

```
import React, { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement as Element);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

I can't find fix on the internet, anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Have you configured eslint & prettier in your project?

Comment: @PatikWadekar yes, here's my configuration on Github: https://github.com/xflameyoke/interactive-comment-section-app/blob/main/.eslintrc

Comment: I think you need to check this configuration `prettier/prettier` in your eslintrc

Comment: Is this really necessary `const root = createRoot(rootElement as Element);` ? 
Wouldn't sth like `const root = createRoot(rootElement);` suffice?

Comment: @user18821127 error after deleting 'as Element':

 Argument of type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element | DocumentFragment'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element | DocumentFragment'.

Comment: It seems the case that you might not have a root element in you `index.html` file.
Any change it got deleted?
You can confirm it exists by `console.log(root)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue by cloning into your repo. It is with `"parser": "babel"` in **eslint.rc** `prettier/prettier`.

Use `"parser": "babel-ts"` or `"parser": "typescript"`.

[image]

[image]