# React typescript eslint error Parsing error: Unexpected token ! How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

So this is my index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App';


const container = document.getElementById('root')!;
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

and this is my eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true
  },
  extends: ['plugin:react/recommended', 'prettier'],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'],
      parserOptions: {
        project: ['./tsconfig.json']
      }
    }
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    },
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint', 'prettier', 'simple-import-sort'],
```

i have tried to install babel-eslint, and add it like a parser? but it didin`t help

so here`s the question, how to solve the problem "error  Parsing error: Unexpected token !"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," in index.tsx?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72991239/283366)

Comment: Nah, it`s not, i have done this solution, but it`s not working for me

Comment: The answer there suggests using `babel-ts` or `typescript` for the `parser` option but you're using `babel-eslint`. What exactly did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `typescript-eslint` as your parser by adding `"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",`.

https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/